# How to resolve "Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'StoreModule' was called."

Tags: angular, gitlab, angular-cli, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've an angular (7) project.

In my package.json, I've a command defined:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
    "e2e-ci": "ng e2e --protractor-config=e2e/protractor.conf.js",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  [...]
}
```

When I just run `npm run build-prod` locally, everything works nice.

Now I'm trying to have this code executed on my gitlab CI.

For this I've the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: node:10

build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm install --quiet
    - npm run build-prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    # install dependencies to use chrome w/ puppeteer
    - apt update && apt install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
    - npm run test-ci
    - npm run e2e-ci

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: $FIREBASE_URL
  only:
   - master
  dependencies:
    - build
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run deploy
```

But when it runs, I get an error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.0-rc2 (10efa505)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Using Docker executor with image node:10 ...
Pulling docker image node:10 ...
Using docker image sha256:64c810caf95adbe21b5f41be687aa77aaebc197aa92f2b2283da5d57269d2b92 for node:10 ...
Running on runner-72989761-project-XYZ-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1555525988-c992ea28...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/XXX/YYY/.git/
Fetching changes...
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/XXX/YYY
 * [new branch]      13-solve-testing-issues -> origin/13-solve-testing-issues
 * [new branch]      develop                 -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      master                  -> origin/master
Checking out e61598d8 as 13-solve-testing-issues...

Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/XYZ/default 
Successfully extracted cache
$ npm install --quiet
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!

> ngrx@2.0.1 postinstall /builds/XXX/YYY/node_modules/ngrx
> node postinstall.js

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 4 packages from 2 contributors and audited 45321 packages in 15.393s
found 27 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 moderate, 20 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
$ npm run build-prod

> YYY@0.1.0 build-prod /builds/XXX/YYY
> ng build --prod


Date: 2019-04-17T18:35:40.652Z
Hash: b0ba2a53437bf05b46d4
Time: 13104ms
chunk {0} runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.01ecbc0fcff9207e8cde.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.a723c36635c3a098c2aa.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.6c94e29121bf3425375a.css (styles) 132 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.9aa141af6e0119c2bcf8.js (scripts) 581 kB [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'StoreModule' was called.
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/ng2.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.
src/app/app.reducer.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/@ngrx/store"' has no exported member 'ActionReducerMap'.
src/app/app.reducer.ts(1,28): error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/@ngrx/store"' has no exported member 'createFeatureSelector'.
src/app/app.reducer.ts(1,51): error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/@ngrx/store"' has no exported member 'createSelector'.
src/app/app.module.ts(42,21): error TS2339: Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof StoreModule'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! YYY@0.1.0 build-prod: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the YYY@0.1.0 build-prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-17T18_35_40_678Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I'm quite new with angular and gitlab. Do you see why can be wrong, or how to find my issue?

**EDIT**
Here is my current tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions":{

        "skipTemplateCodegen": false,
        "strictMetadataEmit": false,
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppProfileComponent } from './app.profile.component';
import { AppMenuComponent, AppSubMenuComponent } from './app.menu.component';
import { AppBreadcrumbComponent } from './app.breadcrumb.component';
import { AppTopBarComponent } from './app.topbar.component';
import { AppFooterComponent } from './app.footer.component';


import { BreadcrumbService } from './breadcrumb.service';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { BeersModule } from './beers/beers.module';


import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { PrimeNgModule } from './primeng/primeng.module';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import {reducers} from './app.reducer';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutes,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        LayoutModule,
        BeersModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        PrimeNgModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppMenuComponent,
        AppSubMenuComponent,
        AppProfileComponent,
        AppBreadcrumbComponent,
        AppTopBarComponent,
        AppFooterComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
         BreadcrumbService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**EDIT**

I changed my yml file to have `node: latest`.

Now I've different errors:

http://pasted.co/e311ee1b

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609#issuecomment-386876693) relevant?

Comment: @MMansour where do you add this?

Comment: `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @J4N Can you share/ Reproduce this in stackblitz. This seems to be an AOT issue. Need to look at your module declarations. Also which version of angular are you using `OpaqueToken` is not available in `Angular 7`.

Comment: can you share your tsconfig file?

Comment: Could be issue with the versions of your ngrx package.

Comment: can you share your AppModule code

Comment: @Amityo I just did

Comment: @NeilStevens Also just did ;)

Comment: @MMansour I tried to specify `"skipTemplateCodegen": false,  "strictMetadataEmit": false` but it still gives me the same issue

Comment: @Ankesh My code is not quite "confidential" but I use some paid library, so I cannot just post everything. If you think you can help, I can give you a git access.

Comment: My main question now is why I cannot reproduce this issue locally, but only on my gitlab. My local computer is a windows and gitlab is linux I think, could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

For starters, you have a dependency for `ngrx` as well as `@ngrx/store`, and only the latter is correct.

You are running a postinstall script from there as well.

Be careful when you `npm add` dependencies as you might be adding malicious code to your application if you are not paying attention.

Second, you are importing `@ngrx/core` which is not needed since version 4 of NgRx, and you are using `^7.4.0`. Make sure to read the migration guides if you are upgrading important functionality in your app:

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v4

and/or

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v7

**OLD ANSWER**

> To inject the root reducers into your application, use an InjectionToken and a Provider to register the reducers through dependency injection.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#injecting-reducers

If you are interested in the details:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/design/architecture.md#need-for-static-value-resolution

Can you show us in what way you are setting up NgRx in your application? You need to register your reducers  through  dependency injection in order to make AOT compilation work properly.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducerToken, reducerProvider } from './index';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken)],
    providers: [reducerProvider]
})
```

**index.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';


export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<any> = {
  // reducers
}

export const reducerToken = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<AppState>>('Registered Reducers');

export const reducerProvider = [
    { provide: reducerToken, useValue: reducers }
];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said, without much success. I modified my `app.reducer.ts`: https://pastebin.com/Rz0ic5uT

And then I import it in my app module as you did:
https://pastebin.com/HWSff4YF

But I've still the same issue, it works in local, but not on gitlab :(

Comment: Can you show me your full package.json? Or at least dependencies? What version of NgRx are you using?

Comment: For starters, you have a dependency for `ngrx` as well as `@ngrx/store`, and only the latter is correct. You are running a postinstall script from there as well. Be careful when you `npm add` dependencies as you might be adding malicious code to your application.

Second, you are importing `@ngrx/core` which is not needed since `@ngrx/store^4.x.x`, and you are using `^7.4.0`. Make sure to read the migration guides if you are upgrading important functionality in your app: https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v4 and/or https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v7

Comment: You are right. I was not having those 2 things initially, but I saw them in 2 others demo, so I tried to add them to see if it was improving anything. I removed them and I've the same issue again. I did not upgrade, I started by using this 7.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out your issue exactly, but about `function calls are not supported in decorators`, at the exported module we can make:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})

export class AppModule { }
@NgModule({})
export class ToSpaceAppModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    const providers = [];
    return {
      ngModule: AppModule,
      providers
    };
  }
}
```

'somewhere'

```
import { ToSpaceAppModule } from '../src/app/app.module';

export function fromSpaceFactory() {
  return import('../src/app/app.module').then(m => m.ToSpaceAppModule );
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    ToSpaceAppModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ToSpaceAppModule ,
      useFactory: fromSpaceFactory
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```