# Function calls are not supported in decorators ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-library

Hello folks find a lot of similar quistions here but did not find solution that works for me (

I'm developing library for angular and in it I use ngRx store. When I'm trying to build library with command `ng build lib --prod` I get an error

```
ERROR: Error during template compile of 'CarolLbLibModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'StoreModule' was called.

An unhandled exception occurred: Error during template compile of 'CarolLbLibModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'StoreModule' was called.
```

in my lib.module I have next code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    PagesModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(
      lbFeatureKey,
      LB_REDUCER_TOKEN
    ),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([GlobalBoardEffects])
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: LB_REDUCER_TOKEN, useFactory: getReducers}
  ]
})
```

LB_REDUCER_TOKEN and `getReducers` looking like

```
export const LB_REDUCER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<LeaderboardState>>('leaderboard reducers');

export function getReducers(): ActionReducerMap<LeaderboardState> {
  // map of reducers
  return {
    [globalBoardReducer.globalBoardFeatureKey]: globalBoardReducer.reducer,
  };
}
```

And just in case it is important my Globalboard reducers code

```
const globalReducer = createReducer(
  initialGlobalBoardState,
  on(GlobalBoardActions.SetData,
    (state: GlobalBoardState, {leaders}) => ({...state, data: [...leaders]})
  ),
);

// tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
export function reducer(state: GlobalBoardState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return globalReducer(state, action);
}
```

So I can't understand what is the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this give you any clues..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734185/how-to-resolve-function-calls-are-not-supported-in-decorators-but-storemodule

Comment: Still don't get it ((